# Outlook.com sender image not shown

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, smtp, sparkpost

When I receive email from my bank or, say, Skype, I see their image in the thumbnail along with one line blurb of the email.

How can I get my company logo to show up in the thumbnail when sending email programatically via sparkpost (email sending service) through a nodejs server?

Comment: `I see their image in the thumbnail` - emails have thumbnails? what email client?

Comment: @JaromandaX [I think he means like this?](https://imgur.com/bGVLfe7) Where it shows the logo next to the sender name.

Comment: none of my mail clients do that, which is why I asked the question :p

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do, or can you confirm it is like @David's example

Comment: I mean like this - https://imgur.com/a/Knh1nQy

Comment: This is from outlook.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an inline image. You do that by converting the image to base64 and then including the content in an image tag.

Here is a sample that will send a red dot [image: red dot] PNG in an email through SparkPost.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/transmissions \
  -H 'Authorization: [YOUR_API_KEY_HERE]' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "options": {
        "open_tracking": true,
        "click_tracking": true
    },
  "campaign_id": "test",
  "recipients": [
    {
      "address": {
        "email": "to@example.com",
        "name": "To recipient"
      }, 
        "tags": []
    }
  ],
  "content": {
    "from": {
      "email": "from@example.com",
      "name": "From address"
    },
    "subject": "My Sample Subject",
    "text": "Test",
    "html": "<p>Test</p> <img src=\"data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\" alt=\"A Red dot\" />"
  }
}

'
```

There are lots of ways to convert images to base64 but here is one example:
    https://www.base64-image.de/

Comment: Yepher, I want something like this - https://imgur.com/a/Knh1nQy (email preview on outlook.com)